# WooCommerce 20% discount coupon and Free shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

We run a webshop and orders over $35,- get free shipping. Working as it should.
We also have 20% discount coupons. Also working as it should.

Now a client emailed us with the following:
She has for $40,- of items in her shopping bag and also a 20% discount code.
Before she applied the discount code free shipping is active. But after adding the discount code the total order value is les then $35,- (it is $32,-) and the Free Shipping is gone and she has to pay the Shipping costs.

Totaly makes sense but is there a way to avoid this? So the discount is not part when calculating the total cart value so she still has Free Shipping?

Comment: Have you checked the `Coupon Discounts` option in the free shipping setting?
https://woocommerce.com/document/free-shipping/#section-2

Comment: you can disable the discount with the using of woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees this action

Comment: @Jainil Thanks a lot, did not know this option was standard in WooCommerce.